# How can I make these links more obvious to click on?

Tags: website-design, fonts, web-fonts, user-experience

Currently working on a redesign for a dental laboratory.

While testing the home page with a user, they never clicked on the links in the subnavigation. They clicked on the larger buttons in the links to the main pages.

The asusmption when I created the wireframe was that the user would click on the descriptive links based on what they needed to do. I thought it would be super convenient to have a list ready for them to just click on the action that they intended to do.

[image: Screenshot of homepage middle section]

I would also appreciate suggestions for

- Font size
- Font color
- Font family for the headings
- List item
- Ideas for images where the thumbnail is supposed to go, or maybe it needs to be removed.
- Round out the buttons a bit more?

Let me know any thoughts and why you feel that way, thanks.

EDIT: After some suggestions from other professionals here, I created another revision (not yet tested with users)

[image: Version 2]

Comment: I think this is more of a ux.stackexchange question. That said I would move the large buttons like 'Services' up and when you click on that have the white box get larger with the blue links inside.

Comment: While it's UX related, it's clearly asking about visual implementation, so I think it makes more sense to keep it here on GD. (ultimately, there's a lot of overlap between GD and UX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a flipped hierarchy issue. The buttons are visually more prominent, but the content they link to is secondary to the content above.

So, one option would be to reverse that hierarchy. Make the current buttons plain links instead and then style the list of links above to look more like a navigation list. Perhaps something like this:

```
-------------------------
Download RX            >
-------------------------
Find a Dropbox         >
-------------------------
Etc                    >
-------------------------
```

Alternatively, the issue may simply be that the links don't look like links. A quick fix might be to simply makes sure the links are all underlined like default links would be.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably get more of what you're looking for over at [UX StackExchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Nonetheless ...

**I would turn these into menus** rather than modules on the page. The three headings would be the top nav and the list of links would drop down. I think that would make your concept much more apparent to the user.

You could keep your thumbnails in the menu, if you're really connected to them. Icons are usually a more effective trigger for the user.

Comment: Good points, the reason that I did not make dropdowns is because of how this page transforms with responsive design. But you do bring up a good point, on how we might be addressing an engineering issue (responsive) and then end up hurting what the user experience by not using what they are used to. 

The full page does have the menu at the top, this was secondary navigation, which was supposed to be convenient (not as much as I anticipated). OK good point about the icons.

Comment: In a responsive design you may find you don't want all the sub-links.